# ios - AdMob interstitial error "Request Error: No ad to show", but when change bundle ID(NEW APP), can load ads,why?

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

The current app has banner ad, and now we need update new version,remove banner bar and using interstitial ad replace;
and now i got interstitial error - no ad to show
but when change bundel ID(new APP) it is working fine, ads alway showing(using the same unit ID)

WHY? 
Can anyone advices? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your app's bundle id is blocked by admob.

Comment: I think this response would be better as a comment.